# Using the url query parameter with a controller

Tags: php, silverstripe, oembed

I am attempting to implement an [oembed](http://oembed.com/) provider using the Silverstripe framework but have come across an issue.

I have a controller routed from the url /omebed.json and it works fine if I call something like /omebed.json?mediaurl=mymovie.mp4.
However the Oembed standard states it should be /omebed.json?url=mymovie.mp4

But Silverstripe internally checks the $_GET['url'] variable and will attempt to route to that page/controller.
So SilverStripe is trying to route to /mymovie.mp4 skipping my controller and hitting the ErrorPage_Controller creating a 404.

I'm thinking im going to have to extend the ErrorPage_Controller and rejig it if the url is oembed.json, but this seems a little hackish.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: What controller are you extending? `PageController`? `ContentController`? Those grab the `$_GET['url']` param in their `init()` method. Why not just extend `Controller` directly?

Comment: Hi, I am extending `Controller` directly and also have  
<pre>
    ---  
    Name: VideoEmbedRoutes  
    After: framework/routes#coreroutes  
    ---  
    Director:  
      rules:  
        'oembed.json//$Action': 'VideoEmbedController'  
</pre>
In my yml file. The issue is `/framework/main.php` is picing up the `$_GET['url']` param and handing it to `Director::direct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending on @Stephen's answer, here is a way to get around that issue without duplicating `main.php` and without modifying it directly.

What I did was create a [`_ss_environment.php` file](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/getting_started/environment_management) which is added early on in the loading process of Silverstripe.

**_ss_environment.php**

```
global $url;
$url = $_GET['raw_url'];
if (isset($_GET['url']))
{
    unset($_GET['url']);
}

// IIS includes get variables in url
$i = strpos($url, '?');
if($i !== false)
{
    $url = substr($url, 0, $i);
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?raw_url=%1 [QSA]
```

So here is what is happening:

- The `.htaccess` is now using `raw_url` instead of `url`
- `_ss_environment.php` is being called early in the loading process, setting the [global `$url` variable that `main.php` normally sets](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/main.php#L65-L102). This is set with `raw_url` rather than `url`.
- To prevent `main.php` to just override it again when it sees your `url` query string parameter, it is unset (Silverstripe seems to reset this later as far as my test is concerned).
- Lastly is a little block of code that [`main.php` would normally run if `$_GET['url']` is set](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/main.php#L85-L93), copied as-is for apparent support in IIS. (If you don't use IIS, you likely won't need it.)

This has a few benefits:

- No update to `main.php` allows upgrading Silverstripe slightly easier in the future
- Runs the minimal amount of code needed to "trick" Silverstripe into thinking it is running normally.

The one obvious drawback to any solution for changing away form the `url` query string parameter is if anything looks at the parameter directly. With how Silverstripe works, it is more likely that code uses the `$url` global variable or the [`Director` class](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Director.html) rather than looking at the query string for the current URL.

I tested this on a 3.1 site by doing the changes I mentioned and:

- Creating a controller called `TestController`
- In the `init` function of the controller, I am running the following:

  ```
  var_dump($_GET['url']);
  var_dump($this->getRequest()->getVars());
  ```
- Visited `/TestController?url=abc123`, saw the value of both dumps have "abc123" as the value for the URL parameter.
- Navigated to a few other custom pages on the site to make sure they were still working (no issues that I saw)

---

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find documentation for the order of inclusion in regards to `_config.php` and `_ss_environment.php`. However, after browsing through the code, I have worked out it is this:

- [`main.php` runs, first main task is to require `core/Constants.php`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/main.php#L55-L58)
- [`Constants.php`'s first task is to search for `_ss_environment.php` in the base folder and potential parent folders.](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/core/Constants.php#L34-L77) If it finds it, it will be included.
- Going back to `main.php` (and **after** the `$_GET['url']` check is done in `main.php`), it will start an `ErrorControlChain` which [it internally does another require for `core/Core.php`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/main.php#L121-L122)
- [Inside `Core.php`, it performs calls for the config manifest](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/core/Core.php#L114-L120)
- [`ConfigManifest.php` exposes the functions to actually add `_config.php` files and for them to be required.](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php)

I could probably go on however I think this gives a pretty good picture of what is going on. I don't really see a way around not using the `_ss_environment.php` file. Nothing else gets included early enough that you can hook into without modifying core code.

Comment: I think so far this is the cleanest option. 
I was hoping to turn this in to a module, however it can't just be installed with composer, since you have to create/modify `_ss_environment.php` and `.htaccess`. This could be documented in the modules readme, but would be cool to get around that. Thanks

Comment: Is there documentation about the order of inclusion? 
Something like `mysite/_config.php` then `_ss_enviroment.php` then `*\_config.php` ?
Basically, could the `_ss_enviroment.php` changes go in to `mymodules\_config.php`?

Comment: Haven't found any documentation but I have had a quick browse of the code and it is `_ss_environment.php` first then `*/_config.php`. I will update my answer to explain what is happening for that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks heaps for that +10000 points for linking back to the relevant PHP files on github

Comment: No problem. I like to be quite detailed with my answers for things like this. Your question was pretty interesting, I couldn't help but answer it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick play with this the other day. And looking at what `main.php` does it *might* be best to hack away at it rather than `ErrorPage_controller`.

For startes SS's default `.htaccess` file does this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /silverstripe

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note the `?url` changing that to something else and then changing `main.php`'s usage as well may/should help or will cause a heap of extra errors and sadness.

To avoid hacking the core/framework, you could change the .htaccess to target a copy of main.php in `mysite` (with appropriate include changes).

Comment: Good point, maybe something like 
`RewriteRule .* mysite/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

Where `mysite/main.php` checks if the URL parameter is one of mine, if it is, handle it, other wise just include  `framework/main.php`

Will check it out and let you know, cheers.

Comment: I'd recommend changing `RewriteRule .* mysite/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` to something like `RewriteRule .* mysite/main.php?apacheurl=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` Then you don't need to test the URL. I can't guarantee that won't cause funky stuff to happen, but is should give you the least mangled URL to work with.